# ACE.oledb Not showing up in list of providers

Tags: ms-access, ssis, oledb, ms-jet-ace

I have an SSIS package that I use for a quick upload to a SQL database. I have recently moved to a different machine. New specs are Win 7 64bit and Office 2010 32bit. Had to have the 32 bit office in order for another program to run correctly. If I build/run the package in SQL Server Data Tools it completes. But if I try to run the solution from a batch script, I get the `microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0 is not registered` error. I have searched many sites, and downloaded what I assume were the appropriate install packages to have the ACE driver.

I used a trick from one of the sites where you make a new text file, and rename it `TEST.UDL`. When I right click on the file, select properties, and go to the provider tab, Microsoft ACE is not listed. Is there another step to register the ACE driver that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was still executing the 64bit dtexec.exe, and had to rewrite my batch script to find the 32bit version.